# Why is overflow: hidden not working? Or is it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an infinite scrolling background for this site, and while it's working perfectly, I can't find a way to hide the part that extends beyond what I want to show. If I'm understanding this right, the background image itself to be larger than its container, and the width of the infinite-scrolling div needs to be 3x the width of the image. I'm not sure what I need to change so that the background only takes up the size of the window, or if I just don't understand the CSS.

The HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>template 002</title>
    <link href="https://willdotjpg.gay/templates/y2ktest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="infinite-scrolling"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
    </div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.infinite-scrolling {
    background: url("https://willdotjpg.gay/images/backgrounds/testbackground.png") repeat-x;
    height: 2520px;
    width: 10080px;
    /* The image width times 3 */
    animation: slide 60s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-3360px, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

[a screenshot of the site in-browser, showing the scrollbars extending way off to the right and bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPl5A.png)

Comment: What do you want to do *exactly*?

Comment: First give a height to container or container parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you wanted:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
}
```

To hide overflow first you have to set a specific height or width and also here you need to set the position fixed.